# How to Insert a Row to a self-referential table with the same primary and foreign key?

Tags: sql, sql-server

In SQL Server 2012, I have a table with a self-referential foreign key that refers to a primary key column which is an `Identity` column. Can you tell me how I can insert a row where the foreign key refers to the primary key of the same row?

```
Create Table MyTable
(
    PersonID int primary key Identity(1,1),
    PersonName varchar(20) not null,
    HeadofPersonID int not null references MyTable(PersonID)
)
```

The row that I need to insert:

```
1, 'Mickey Mouse', 1
```

In this case, Mickey has the identity generated primary key `1` and Mickey is also the Head of himself (and possibly others). What do I need to mention in the foreign key in my insert statement?

Comment: in this scenario if it is the root / parent, then you would usually set it to `null` to signify it's the top level, not sure if that would break the constraint though

Comment: This is not a typical use case. Normally the foreign key column would be nullable, so that in the case where PersonID and HeadofPersonID are the same you would insert NULL into the HeadofPersonID column.

Comment: I don't think this can be done, a better solution would be to have two records for Mickey Mouse - one in the head position and one in the employee position

Comment: No can do, sorry.  The record cannot reference itself before it's created, but it can't be created without a referenced record since your foreign key is not null... It's a catch 22. Your best option would be to allow null values in the foreign key column.

Comment: @ZoharPeled That's not 100% true... one could set IDENTITY_INSERT and manually insert both the primary and foreign key values, but I agree that would not be best practice.

Comment: @BrianDriscoll Yeah, you're correct.

Comment: @BrianDriscoll That's right. I can insert a row such as `Insert into MyTable values(1,'Mickey Mouse',1)` if I perform an Identity Insert. Since my requirement is to insert through a program, I guess it's best to Insert first with a null value for foreign key - I would need to remove the not null constraint though.

Comment: Yes you definitely do not want to hack your way into forcing this data. The obvious next step would be a recursive cte to build the tree and if you have a row referencing itself you can't use recursion because it would be an endless loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the `not null`constraint from your foreign key column declaration and insert `NULL` in **HeadofPersonID** as the head of your heirarchy:

```
Create Table MyTable
(
    PersonID int primary key Identity(1,1),
    PersonName varchar(20) not null,
    HeadofPersonID int references MyTable(PersonID)
)
```

Comment: With this you can use `where HeadofPersonID is null` to find the root(s). If you want to enforce a single root you can use a unique index: `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX UK_MyTable_SingleRoot ON dbo.MyTable(HeadofPersonID) WHERE key IS NULL;`